# mysql count rows from one table using group and join from 2nd table

Tags: mysql, database, join

I need a some guidance.  I have found a flaw in my coding.

I have 2 tables:

table 1: **eventinfo**

```
id
evid
eventtype
division
evtdate
tod
```

Plus more fields, but not important for this

SQL query:

```
SELECT evid, eventype, evtdate , tod 
FROM `eventinfo` 
WHERE evid =  105
```

```
eventtype     division  evtdate tod
beginner        0   2018-02-17  AM
intermediate    1   2018-02-17  AM
intermediate    2   2018-02-17  AM
advanced        1   2018-02-17  AM
advanced        2   2018-02-17  AM
beginner        0   2018-02-18  AM
intermediate    1   2018-02-18  AM
intermediate    2   2018-02-18  AM
advanced        1   2018-02-18  AM
advanced        2   2018-02-18  AM
```

table 2: **entries**

```
id
entid
firstname
lastname
eventcat
evtdate
division
tod
```

plus more rows, but not important for this.

SQL query:

```
SELECT evid, eventcat, evtdate , tod , COUNT( * ) AS count 
FROM entries 
WHERE evtid= '105' and  evtstatus= 'pending' 
GROUP BY evtdate, tod , evntcat
```

```
eventcat        evtdate     tod count
Advanced        2018-02-17  AM  35
Intermediate    2018-02-17  AM  18
Beginner        2018-02-17  AM  4
Advanced        2018-02-18  AM  35
Intermediate    2018-02-18  AM  18
```

On the page I need, I need to count entries into this course/event to see how many more seats are available.  (this way I know if I need to "tell people they can't enter"  I need the grouping, because the division doesn't matter at this point of the coding.

OK,  here's my problem.  The above query works great, EXCEPT my flaw is where there's no entries for the course/event yet.  I need the above to show that the 2nd date beginner is 0. (which i understand my current query will not show)

```
eventcat        evtdate     tod count
Advanced        2018-02-17  AM  35
Intermediate    2018-02-17  AM  18
Beginner        2018-02-17  AM  4
Advanced        2018-02-18  AM  35
Intermediate    2018-02-18  AM  18
**Beginner        2018-02-18  AM  0** <-----
```

I've tried some some joins the tables, but with no luck.  (odd results and the database says I need to SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1)

Any help would be greatly appreciative.

Comment: You need to `left join` the 2 tables.

Comment: Why would you want 2018-02-18 for the "Beginner"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, one method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select ei.*,
       (select count(*)
        from entries e
        where e.evtid = ei.evtid and e.evtstatus = 'pending'
       ) as cnt
from eventinfor ei
```

Comment: Thank this was very close to what I needed.  some changes to where  statement and grouping statement after the from and voila.  I was thinking this is what I needed to do, just couldn't get it to work.  Thanks again!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
 SELECT i.eventtype, i.evtdate , i.tod , COUNT( * ) AS count 
FROM eventinfo AS i
LEFT JOIN entries as e On e.eventcat = i.eventtype
GROUP BY i.eventtype, i.evtdate , i.tod ;
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/24640b6/8)

Comment: The 1 and 2 in the table 1 are the divisions. (guess I should have put A & B to specify it better)  The divisions are used to split the entries into different courses later.  They are not "counted".  This is why I need the group eventinfo table.  The counting needs to go the other table, but show 0 if there is not an entry.  Let me play with this to see, but I haven't had luck with the left joins. But I may have been setting it up wrong.  I use evid to "link" the 2 tables.